# How to embed an image in email with lotusscript?

Tags: lotus-notes, lotusscript, lotus

I have a class that it has a method to send email using HTML. This method includes the image like an attachment into the email.

And I have a form with a rich text field where the users will attachment a image.

I have a problem with it:

- I need the image show embedded into the email and in it must be in the correct place. The attachment appears at the beginning.
- And other problem: the method haven't got especified the rich text field. So I need to know how to show only a specific field.

**Method to send HTML mail**

```
' Sub to send an email with attachments
Public Sub SendEmailHTMLAttachments()

    ' General variables
    Dim ws As New NotesUIWorkspace
    Dim ns As New NotesSession
    Dim maildoc As NotesDocument
    Dim doc As NotesDocument
    Dim body As NotesMIMEEntity
    Dim mh As NotesMIMEHeader
    Dim mc As NotesMIMEEntity
    Dim stream As NotesStream
    Dim link As New Link

    Set maildoc = ws.Currentdocument.Document
    Set doc = ws.Currentdocument.Document

    ' Dont convert text to rich text
    ns.ConvertMIME = False

    ' Configure the mail
    maildoc.Form = "Memo"
    maildoc.Subject = me.m_subject
    maildoc.SendTo = me.m_sendto
    maildoc.CopyTo = me.m_sendtocc
    maildoc.blindCopyTo = me.m_sendtobcc

    ' Create the MIME headers
    Set body = maildoc.Createmimeentity
    Set mh = body.Createheader({MIME-Version})
    Call mh.Setheaderval("1.0")
    Set mh = body.Createheader("Content-Type")
    Call mh.Setheadervalandparams({multipart/alternative})

    ' Send the plain text part first
    Set mc = body.Createchildentity()
    Set stream = ns.Createstream()
    Call mc.Setcontentfromtext(stream, {text/plain}, ENC_NONE)

    ' Now send the HTML part. Order is important!
    Set mc = body.Createchildentity()
    Set stream = ns.Createstream()
    Call stream.Writetext(|<html lang="es">|)
    Call stream.Writetext(|<head>|)
    Call stream.Writetext(|<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">|)
    Call stream.Writetext(|<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">|)
    Call stream.Writetext(|</head>|)
    Call stream.Writetext(|<body>|)
    Call stream.Writetext(|<div style="background-color: #897d7d; border-radius: 0.5em; width: auto; height: 50px;">
                        <h1 style="color: white; text-align: center; padding: 0.1em;
                        font-family: Cambria, Cochin, Georgia, Times, 'Times New Roman', serif;">| & me.m_header & |</h1>
                        </div>|)
    Call stream.Writetext(|<p>| & me.m_body & |</p>|)
    Call stream.Writetext(|<a href="| & link.GetLink() & |" target="_blank"
                        style="background-color: #A01314; color: white; padding: 14px 25px; text-align: center;
                        text-decoration: none; display: inline-block; border-radius: 1em;">Link to Form</a>|)
    Call stream.Writetext(|</body>|)
    Call stream.Writetext(|</html>|)
    Call mc.Setcontentfromtext(stream, {text/html;charset="utf-8"}, ENC_NONE)

    ' Close the stream
    Call stream.Close()

    ' Send it
    Call maildoc.Send(False)

    Delete link

End Sub
```

**Event to send email (Button)**

```
Sub Click(Source As Button)

    Dim subject As String
    Dim header As String
    Dim body As String
    Dim sendto(1 To 9) As String
    Dim sendtocc(1 To 3) As String
    Dim sendtobcc(1 To 3) As String
    Dim alert As String
    Dim flagalert As Boolean

    subject = "Form Lotus Notes: Test"
    header = "Form Lotus Notes: Test"
    body = "This is an example email using <b>HTML</b>."
    body = body + "<p>Url: <a href='www.google.es'>Google</a></p>."
    sendto(1) = "people"
    alert = ""

    Dim msj As New Mensaje(subject, header, body, sendto, "", "", alert, False)

    Call msj.SendEmailHTMLAttachments

    Delete msj

End Sub
```

**Example when I recieve the email**

[image]

What am i doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

What you're doing wrong is that you're creating a multipart/alternative message with no image data and you're relying on Domino to somehow figure out what you really want to do. It can't.

You have to create the entire MIME message, with a multipart/mixed part that contains a multipart/related and a multipart/alternative parts.

The multipart/related part must contain an image/gif (or some other valid image format) part that has Content-disposition: Embedded; filename=xxx, and you'll need to stream the encoded bytes of the image into that part -- which isn't easy and I don't have code to show you how to do it. I think that DXL is probably the way most people have approached this, although I'm pretty sure that the MIDAS Rich Text API (not free) makes it much easier.

The multipart/alternative part is what you have in that it contains your text/plain and text/html parts, but your text/hteml part needs to include an img tag that correctly refers to the image data that is inside the multipart/related using src=cid:xxx, where the xxx matches what you put in the filename=xxx for the image.

Answer (score 0):

One way to solve this is using the apache commons email java library https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-email/